# Comparing goodness of fit in linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, linear, goodness-of-fit

I would like to compare the goodness of fit for a regression model fitted to two separate groups (patients and controls).

I want to compare goodness of fit (as opposed to difference in slope). I thought one way of doing this would be comparing the R value of the model in patients vs the value in controls in a Fisher R-to-z comparison.

My question is whether it is more appropriate to use the 'Multiple R-squared' or the 'Adjusted R-squared'. Additionally if the Adjusted R squared is preferred then how would one deal with negative values?

Or please do let me know if the whole approach is wrong headed.

Comment: What is your broader goal?

Comment: To determine whether a relationship appears to be present in one group, but not in the other, and ascribe a degree of statistical significance to this

Comment: Note that showing that there is a relationship in one group and not in the other is not a basis for concluding that there is a difference between the two groups (doing so amounts to accepting the null for one of the groups). To answer your question, you need to directly test for an interaction.

Comment: Many thanks - I suggested performing an R-to-z in order to address this?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at goodness of fit is not a, um, good fit for your actual goal, "to determine whether a relationship appears to be present in one group, but not in the other, and ascribe a degree of statistical significance to this".  If there were a relationship in one group but not the other, then the relationship would differ by group.  That is an interaction.  To test this, fit a model with $X$ and $Y$, an indicator variable for group membership, and an interaction between $X$ and group.  The test of that interaction is the first thing you need.  In R, the model might look like this:

```r
lm(y~x*group)
```

You may want to follow that up by testing if the relationship is significant in each of the groups.  Since your group variable is a dummy code (0, 1), the 'main effect' of x is a test of the relationship between X and Y in the reference group.  The simplest way to get the test of the relationship in the other group is to change the reference level of `group`, refit the model and then examine the main effect of X again.  Here is a simple example, coded in R:

```r
set.seed(1)                                                  # making this reproducible
x     = runif(n=20, min=0, max=10)                           # making x values
group = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10)                            # making the groups
group = factor(group)                                        #  & making it a factor
y     = 5 + 1*x[1:10] + rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)              # the y values for A
y     = c(y, 5 + rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1))                    # adding the y values for B
coef(summary(lm(y~x*group)))                                 # model w/ A as reference level
#               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  5.9802513 0.51218827 11.6758849 3.056083e-09
# x            0.7980242 0.08161474  9.7779420 3.750885e-08
# groupB      -0.2107658 0.77806193 -0.2708856 7.899425e-01
# x:groupB    -0.9141179 0.12543254 -7.2877257 1.819064e-06
group = relevel(group, ref="B")                              # changing reference to B
coef(summary(lm(y~x*group)))                                 # the second model
#               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  5.7694855 0.58569919  9.8505950 3.385481e-08
# x           -0.1160937 0.09524891 -1.2188456 2.405689e-01
# groupA       0.2107658 0.77806193  0.2708856 7.899425e-01
# x:groupA     0.9141179 0.12543254  7.2877257 1.819064e-06
```

The p-value for the test of the interaction is the last column, last row in both models.  Note that the p-value is the same.  The 'main effect' of `x` is different between the two models, though.  That is for the main effect of x in the reference level, which is changed between the two models.  It is significant in group A, but not in group B.  Be careful, though!  You cannot conclude that there is 'no relationship' for group B just because the relationship is not significant.

Comment: What about an ANOVA with M1 = `lm(y ~ group * x)` and M2 = `lm(y ~ group + I(x * (group == "B")))`? Wouldn't that test the OP's hypothesis in one analysis step?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's simpler, @dipetkov.  I gather the OP has (at least) 3 questions: relationship in A, in B, & do they differ.  So they need 3 p-values.  I do this via 2 models.  You also have 2 models.  You can test the relationship in B without releveling & refitting the model, but it's more complicated.  I teach how to do it in class, but then I show how you can get the same answer by just releveling & refitting, & students always prefer that ;-).

Comment: (Trying to explain myself better) I assumed the OP's interest is "To determine whether a relationship appears to be present in one group, but not in the other." That is: `x:betaA != 0 & x:betaB == 0`. I'm wondering if this (comlpex) hypothesis be expressed with one test. I can see that it can be tested separately with first `x:betaA != 0` and then `x:betaB == 0`.

Comment: But this is also not trivial: (a) we can't use alpha = 0.05 for both and then claim alpha = 0.05 for the compound hypothesis; (b) Only `x:betaB == 0` is the usual null of "parameter = constant". On the other hand, I no longer think that the anova I suggested works for this either.

Comment: @dipetkov, I see.  I'm not sure if it could be done in a single test.  But even if it could, say the answer was 'no', now what?  You wouldn't know if that's because the relationships don't differ, or b/c both have a relationship, etc.

Comment: The "now what" is a good question but if that was the main question, then the best advice may be to not do multiple hypothesis testing at all. (Also it depends on the situation which the OP didn't describe.) Instead I got interested in a more theoretical interpretation of the question as I haven't seen it asked before on CV.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly the same number of estimates, I believe both $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ would produce similar results. To my knowledge, the adjusted $R^2$ penalizes the inflation of the $R^2$ that comes from increasing the number of predictors. Given the two equations are equivalent, you should be fine by going with the regular $R^2$.

**** OLDER RESPONSE ****
Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Disregard the response below:

The question is a bit vague. I'm assuming you are using R. Then,

```
    mod1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=patients)
    mod2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=controls)
    anova(mod1, mod2)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question about *goodness of fit*?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood @RobMcC 's question, but it seems to me that he needs to know if the equations are different. It is very hard to evaluate without a more detailed example.

Comment: There's a more fundamental issue here concerning what an ANOVA of two models using two different sets of data even means, how to interpret it, and how it might be related to the question.  I am trying to suggest that your answer looks problematic and requires further explanation, regardless of how you might understand the question.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but isn't the anova here effectively examining whether there is a difference in slope as opposed to a difference in goodness of fit?

Comment: @RobMcC: you normally test the difference of F using `anova()`.
For example, if you had mod1 with x1 and mod2 with x2 and x3, the `anova()` would test the hypothesis that either x2 or x3 are significantly different from zero:

          mod1 <- lm(y ~ x1, data=p)
          mod2 <- lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3. data=p)

Comment: Now, I never used it to test if the fit is different between models using different data. Suppose you had exactly the same n in each dataset, you would have zero degrees of freedom in difference.